# How do I create dynamic strings from static data

Tags: php, mysql

In a PHP/MySQL script I'm reading XLS files and checking them for errors based on a set of rules and output error messages to the user so they know what to fix. Most of the rules are common for many columns so the only thing that changes in the error msg is the column name or the value that it should be checked against. Instead of hardcoding the messages in PHP I want to pull them from mysql table `error_messages` but also be able to change them according to each column.

Example:
Error1: "Column 'Name' contains invalid chars."
Error2: "Column 'Surname' contains invalid chars."

If I store "Column XXX contains invalid chars." in the mysql table `error_messages`, how do I display it by changing only XXX to each column name?

I could use a PHP function that replaces XXX with any string and outputs the message but is this the best way to go? Any smarter ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store in your database as:

> Column '%s' contains invalid chars.

and use [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$message = "Column '%s' contains invalid chars.";
$display = sprint($message, 'surname');
echo $display;
```

Comment: omg... of course! I use it a million times a day to construct queries, thank you Mark.

Comment: Sometimes things are __too__ blindingly obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

As you will find in general when you ask design questions, there are multiple ways to solve this problem.

One solution is to store `printf`-format strings like so: 
`Column %s contains invalid chars.`

But then you run into the issue of storing tons of redundant data. You could put all the distinct errors into another table, and then store IDs to error strings in your original table. This approach would give you the benefit of being able to change the error strings in one location and having the change propagate automatically everywhere.

Another possibility would be to use the MySQL `ENUM` type ([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)) and handle all the printing in PHP.